# how to re-order runtime classpath when running application using eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm running a java application using eclipse, can I re-order runtime or class-path or exclude a jar from the class path? this jar is a part of other project that is indirectly referenced by the project I run.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the order of the project dependencies.

On the project, right-click -> Properties -> Java Build Path.

On the Order and Export tab you can select a dependency and then move it up or down.

Comment: As I said - I'm talking about the run time class path and not the build class path.

Comment: So, did it not work when you tried it? By default, the runtime classpath is the same as the build path. If you want more control for a given launch configuration you can open the lauch config (Run -> Run Configurations...) and move things up and down on the Classpath tab.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on project-> Properties -> Build Path -> Order and Export for javac

Run -> Run configurations -> Classpath of project's main class for jre